# Is InputStream same as InputStreamReader when a character has 8 bits?

Tags: java, file, char, inputstream, inputstreamreader

I was reading about `InputStream` and `InputStreamReader`.
Most of the people said that `InputStream` is for bytes and `InputStreamReader` is for text.

So I created a simple file with only one character, which was 'a'.
When I used `InputStream` to read the file and convert it to a `char` it printed the letter 'a'. And when I did the same thing but this time with `InputStreamReader` it also gave me the same result.

So where was the difference? I thought `InputStream` would not be able to give the letter 'a'.

Does this mean that when a character has 8 bits, there will be no difference between `InputStream` and `InputStreamReader`? Is it true that there will be only a difference between them when a character has more than one `byte`?

Answer (score 1):

No, `InputStream` and `InputStreamReader` are not the same even for 8 bit characters.

Look at  [`InputStream`'s `read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) method without parameter. It returns an `int` but according to the documentation, a byte (range 0 to 255) is returned or -1 for EOF. The other read methods work with arrays of bytes.

`InputStreamReader` inherits from `Reader`. [`Reader`'s read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--) method without a parameter also returns an `int`. But here the int value (range 0 to 65535) is interpreted as a character or -1 for EOF. The other read methods work with arrays of `char` directly.

The difference is the encoding. `InputStreamReader`'s constructors require an explicit encoding or the platform's default encoding is used. The encoding is the translation between bytes and characters.

You said: *"When I used InputStream to read the file and convert it to a char it printed the letter 'a'."* So you read the byte and converted it to a character manually. This conversion part is built into `InputStreamReader` using an encoding for the translation.

Even for one byte character sets there are differences. So your example is the letter "a" which has hex value 61 for [Windows ANSI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Windows-1252) encoding (named "Cp1252" in Java). But for the encoding [IBM-Thai](http://wutils.com/encodings/ibm-thai) the byte 0x61 is interpreted as "/".

So the people said right. `InputStream` is for binary data and on top of that there is `InputStreamReader` which is for text, translating between binary data and text according to an encoding.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.io.*;

public class EncodingExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Prepare the byte buffer for character 'a' in Windows-ANSI
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos, "Cp1252"));
    writer.print('a');
    writer.flush();
    final byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();

    readAsBytes(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
    readWithEncoding(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer), "Cp1252");
    readWithEncoding(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer), "IBM-Thai");
  }

  /**
   * Reads and displays the InputStream's bytes as hexadecimal.
   * @param in The inputStream
   * @throws Exception
   */
  private static void readAsBytes(InputStream in) throws Exception {
    int c;
    while((c = in.read()) != -1) {
      final byte b = (byte) c;
      System.out.println(String.format("Hex: %x ", b));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Reads the InputStream with an InputStreamReader and the given encoding.
   * Prints the resulting text to the console.
   * @param in The input stream
   * @param encoding The encoding
   * @throws Exception
   */
  private static void readWithEncoding(InputStream in, String encoding) throws Exception {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);
    int c;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) c);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Interpreted with encoding '%s': %s", encoding, sb.toString()));
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
Hex: 61 
Interpreted with encoding 'Cp1252': a
Interpreted with encoding 'IBM-Thai': /
```

Comment: You said that "This conversion part is built into InputStreamReader using an encoding for the translation". Then why is this line `sb.append((char) c);` needed? Why do you need to convert to a `char` if the `Reader` is for text? I thought there would be a method like `getString` for the `Reader` so that this step to convert to a `char` is not needed

Comment: Yes the API is a litte bit awkward. `int` is used as a return value instead of `char` because of the additional value of -1 for EOF. This would not be possible only with `char`. But the point is the meaning of the return value which is described in the documentation. The meaning of the return value in `InputStream`'s read method is totally different despite of the same formal types. Additionally the `InputStreamReader` is often wrapped in a `BufferedReader` to read the file line by line via `readLine()`.